# Android System services not available

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm tyring to get data from my website and then put that info into a spinner. I've used some tutorials and i came up with this code

```
package com.thenewboston.christian;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class hospitalhttp extends Activity{

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

private static String url_all_products = "http://www.photosbychristian.com/ems/hospitals.php";

//private static final String TAG_HID = "hid";
private static final String TAG_HOSPITAL = "hospital";

JSONArray hosps = null;
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinnertest);

    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

}


class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(hospitalhttp.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading hospitals. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());


        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        try {
            // products found
            // Getting Array of Products
            hosps = json.getJSONArray("PA");

            // looping through All Products
            for (int i = 0; i < hosps.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = hosps.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                //String id = c.getString(TAG_HID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_HOSPITAL);

                adapter.add(name);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 */

                Spinner state = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                state.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

I try and run my app and i get this error

```
02-22 22:29:48.131: E/AndroidRuntime(1200): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.thenewboston.christian/com.thenewboston.christian.hospitalhttp}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

So i move all of this after the oncreate bolck and i still get the same error

```
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

private static String url_all_products = "http://www.photosbychristian.com/ems/hospitals.php";

//private static final String TAG_HID = "hid";
private static final String TAG_HOSPITAL = "hospital";

JSONArray hosps = null;
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
```

And so i have no idea what to do know any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Post the entire stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the code around is not going to help. Java is a scoped language, it doesn't matter if something is placed after or before a method. It is still in the same scope.

The issue is probably raised by this line:

```
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
```

You want to load a layout in an *object scoped* initializer. This kind of code runs even before the constructor. You must move the value assignment into the `onCreate` method like this:

```
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.spinnertest);

   adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

   new LoadAllProducts().execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So i move all of this after the oncreate bolck and i still get the same error

That code cannot be inside a method, as you are declaring static values. Hence, that code must reside outside any method, which means that it will be executed before *any* method, and therefore will be executed before `onCreate()`.

Something in there -- probably your `JSONParser` -- is trying to do something that cannot be done until *after* `super.onCreate()` has been executed in your `onCreate()` method. Your Java stack trace will tell you specifically which of these lines (if any) is the source of your difficulty. You then need to have that code be executed *after* `super.onCreate()` is called, such as by putting it at the end of your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Wouldn't the `adapter` declaration also be to blame? That is actually getting a context passed.

Comment: @A--C: Possibly. I wouldn't have expected it to try using anything like a `LayoutInflater` in its constructor, though, so that's why I was guessing `JSONParser`.